# indentation of enumerate items inside quotation

Tags: indentation, enumerate

I have the following LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
This is some text. This is still more text. Here is a few more words.
\begin{quotation}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}
\end{quotation}
\end{document}
```

I would like to create the following:

```
This is some text. This is still more text. Here is a few more words.

    1. First item
    2. Second item
    3. Third item
```

But instead I end up with this:

```
This is some text. This is still more text. Here is a few more words.

     1. First item
 2. Second item
 3. Third item
```

That is, the first item is being more indented than the others. How could this behaviour be changed? I suppose I could use the `enumitem` package, but unfortunately could not figure out how to do it.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

With warmest regards,

Comment: Use `quote` instead of `quotation`.

Answer (score 6):

```
\mbox{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{enumerate}
```

works, (hard to justify the behaviour of nested list environments really, but impossible to change now). You see similar effects if you use enumerate in theorem environments which are similarly usually list environments.

Comment: `\box{}` is to produce an empty line? And the negative vertical space to force the first item to move up? Is this the idea behind your commands?

Comment: @Sigur more or less, yes.

Answer (score 4):

Changing from `quotation` to `quote`, solves the problem as seen below:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{quote}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}
\end{quote}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]